# Android: i unable to get the correct date from the call log history?

Tags: java, android

my code is like this

```
int dateColumn =  c.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE);
long callDate = c.getInt(dateColumn);
SimpleDateFormat datePattern = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd-MM-yyyy:h:m:s:a");
datePattern.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
String date_str = datePattern.format(new Date(callDate));
serializer.text(date_str);
Log.v("",""+date_str);
```

it gives output as:23-08-1969:4:34:05:PM
instead of correct date it gives me long age date .
how to get the correct date can any body tell me....
    String date_str = datePattern.format(new Date(callDate));
    serializer.text(date_str);
    Log.v("",""+date_str);

Comment: can you define format of correctdate

Comment: try change `serializer.text(date_str);` to `date_str = serializer.text(date_str);`

Comment: @SamirMangroliya how can i define?

Comment: @idiottiger sorry serializer means in my project  XmlSerializer serializer = Xml.newSerializer();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suspect the problem is here:

```
long callDate = c.getInt(dateColumn);
```

Given that you want a `long` value, I'd expect this to be:

```
long callDate = c.getLong(dateColumn);
```